# Starting and stopping mysql server. Shorten and make automatic

Tags: command-line, shortcut, services, mysql

Currently I start and stop mysql with the following command

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

It is quite a long command to remember.  How can I set it up so that I can start and stop it with a single command.  Something like.

```
sudo mysql-server start
```

I am thinking I would need to crete a symbolic link somewhere for this to work?  Also one last option; how can I make it so that it runs on bootup by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create an alias in your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile file.

Check with `ls -la0 ~/` if one of the files already exist, else create one with:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
```

After opening .bash_profile with `nano ~/.bash_profile` add the lines:

```
alias iwanttostartmysqlwithareallyshortcommand='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start'
alias iwanttostopmysqlwithareallyshortcommand='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop'
```

write the file to disk with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and exit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

Then enter:

```
source .bash_profile
```

In the future you just have to enter

```
iwanttostartmysqlwithareallyshortcommand
```

or

```
iwanttostopmysqlwithareallyshortcommand
```

to start or stop mysql after entering your password.

A shorter alias like `iwanttostartmysqlnow` works also. Even really, really short ones are possible like `stm` (= **st**art **m**ysql) or `spm` (= **s**to**p** **m**ysql). They mustn't collide with other aliases or valid commands though. The shortest I have found - and easy to remember - are `1` to start and `0` to stop mysql. ;-)

---

To answer your second question:

If you have installed the [latest](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) MySQL from Oracle a launch daemon should have been installed in /Library/LaunchDaemons already.

If you have installed another mysql package (e.g. homebrew) you may use the example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/osx-installation-launchd.html) and adapt it.

Slightly modified example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Save the XML as a file named /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist

Adjust the file permissions using the Apple recommended owner "root", owning group "wheel", and file permissions "644"

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Enable this new MySQL service with:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the alias answer.  This is another route I found whilst looking.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server /usr/bin/mysql.server
```

can now stop and start with

```
sudo mysql.server start
```

```
sudo mysql.server stop
```

Comment: You should not add/alter files in /usr/bin as part of the OS and Apple can add or remove them and in El Capitan they have made it difficult to do

Comment: what alternative do you propose?

Comment: The other answer - or link to /usr/local/bin